# Cannot access mounted partition after using dd

Tags: debian, data-recovery, dd, disk, lsblk

I have used following command to create an image of mounted partition `sda1`:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 'conv=noerror,sync'
```

where sda1 is the one I want to "backup" and sdb1 is obviously target, but documentation was not very clear, and I should have used also filename, such as `image.iso`

What happened, I got message files copied or something like that and after reboot, I get into emergency mode and I cant see mounted partition `/data` which was there before.

I am not quite sure what I have done but when I enter `cd /data/` I get in, so it must exist, but I can't see it when I do `lsblk`.

Structure or all partitions after running `lsblk` command is this:

```
sda
 -sda1
sdb
 -sdb1
   -lvm--group1-root
   -lvm--group1-android
   -lvm--group1-tmp
   -lvm--group1-home
   -lvm--group1-var
   **-lvm--group1-data** this one is not here anymore and it was before running dd command
```

Is there a way how to get it back somehow?
What did I actually do? Why is only `data` not here and not the entire `sdb1` partition?

Comment: Do you have a file called `/etc/lvm/backup/lvm-group1`? Does it still reference `data`?

Comment: I do, and it does not. There is no `/data` at all.

Comment: Is it possible that disks got swapped? Because now I realized that `sda` had 1.9GB and `sdb` had 60GB and now it is swapped. Because I remember `sdb1` had mounted `\data`.

Comment: You 'copied' the partition. What you really did was clone the partition. The unique UUID number for the partition is now in two places, no longer unique. Your boot loader may be getting confused and trying to use the clone.

Comment: When you cloned the partition to sdb, was the partition table on sdb ready to see the new partition as it is? Most likely not. Also the disk identifiers `sda` and `sdb` may change where it points to on each boot.

Comment: @jc__ yes bootloader is confused and it is "starting a job..." on every boot...I am not a linux experienced user so I would be greatful for any help how to fix it.